# Where in event cycle does gridview get datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, lifecycle, objectdatasource

I'm trying to achieve the same thing as this [poster](http://forums.asp.net/t/986566.aspx) and I'm following what one of the [answers](http://forums.asp.net/post/2490145.aspx) says I need to do.

Here is my method

```
public void DisplayItemRangeForCurrentPage()
{
    var totalRecords = ((DataView)gvMagicalSearchResults.DataSource).Count;
    var endRecord = gvMagicalSearchResults.PageSize * (gvMagicalSearchResults.PageIndex + 1);
    var startsRecods = endRecord - gvMagicalSearchResults.PageSize;

    if (endRecord > totalRecords)
        endRecord = totalRecords;

    if (startsRecods == 0) startsRecods = 1;
    if (endRecord == 0) endRecord = totalRecords;

    var str = new StringBuilder();
    str.Append((string)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("magicalResx", "GrivSearchCountMessage_Shows"));
    str.Append(" " + startsRecods + " - " + endRecord + " ");
    str.Append((string)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("magicalResx", "GrivSearchCountMessage_OfTotal"));
    str.Append(" " + totalRecords + " ");

    ltrResultsCount.Text = str.ToString();
}
```

No matter where I call this method it throws an "Object not set to an instance of an object" error on the `var totalRecords = ((DataView)gvMagicalSearchResults.DataSource).Count;` line.

I tried calling it in several GridView/ObjectDataSource events. I tried calling it in `PreRender`, `OnLoad`, `Render` - Alas, none of them worked...

So can anyone tell me where in the event cycle a gridview gets its datasource?

Answer (score 0):

It happens on the `GridView.OnDataBound`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound%28v=vs.90%29.aspx